# Windows 7 won't open any program

Tags: windows-7

I'm running windows7 32-bits. Recently I had a problem and I formatted the c: drive and installed Windows again. After that I ran into another problem, every time I tried to open a program or folder, the explorer encountered an error and restarted, I later found out that the problem was on a corrupted ieproxy.dll file and, through the CMD I solved it. Now, it seems that a similar, but worse problem appeared. Basically I can't open anything, not even the CMD. Just some particular (almost seem random) programs open: control panel, uninstall/repair programs, uTorrent and maybe another few. No browsers open.. Also, it's the same in safe mode and I can only restart with the 5 second push on the power button.

I wandered around the net and I couldn't find many similar problems, the ones I found, were easier to solve, basically it was a virus, or weren't solved at all.
I have some doubts about the reliability of my hard disk by now, 'cause the older problem had its origin, according to some sources, in a hard disk write or read error.

Any ideas of how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD
2. Restart your computer
3. When asked if you want to boot from your DVD drive, do so.
4. Choose your language, click Next.
5. Click 'Repair your computer'
6. Select operating system you want repair.

--

Do you have a virus scanner? I could be that it is a virus that infected your registery. Then no program will run.

--

And did any programs run after you installed Windows?

Comment: I can't open anything, including the anti-virus. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I will try to follow the instructions

Comment: yes, they all worked for a while

Answer (score 0):

You've already mentioned 2 "more-than-likely" probabilities: Malware or drive failure. Another possible cause of failure would be general data corruption. Although that's unlikely because you re-installed Windows correct?

For potential malware, I'd suggest running Unhide.exe (can be found at bleepingcomputer.com). That coupled with ComboFix and Malwarebytes usaually takes care of most issues. I've seen some more serious cases that require the use of TDSKiller to rule out/remove rooktkits.

IF you can make it far enough to test the drive, attempt to run `sfc /scannow`. This will check the Windows file system (ruling out troubles linked directly with OS). Next use `chkdsk /f` you should. Allow the scan to run at next boot. If you're unable to run either built in utility, Check out Hirens Boot disc. There are several tools on the disk that will scan your drive and isolate potential problems.

I'd also ask what did you do in order to "fix" the PC the first time with CMD?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions!

I renamed the ieproxy.dll to ieproxy.old and with some command I got a new ieproxy.dll

Comment: I used these instructions:

"Rename this file

C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll to ieproxy.old

Press Windows+R key and copy this line

C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-ie-ieproxy_31bf3856ad364e35_9.4.8112.16447_none_a89ee90164e1bdc6

and click ok

Copy ieproxy.dll from location and paste it in

C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"

Comment: Gotcha. That series of commands replaced the specific file. As you now know that missing dll is more than likely a symptom of a bigger issue.

Comment: really? what can I do now, then?